# BlackBerry Torch scrolling issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

I have created an app which is working fine on BlackBerry bold but when I installed it on Torch the screen is not scrolling..
I have used Manager with enabled vertical scrolling and added it to another master vertical field manager?
Did any one get this issue before ??

the code for the manager is below

```
public class TableManager extends Manager {

public int HEIGHT = 0;

public TableManager(int height) {
    super(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH|Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
    HEIGHT = height;
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return Constants.width * 90 / 100;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return HEIGHT;
}

protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {     
    int y = 150;
    try{
        int count = getFieldCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Field field = getField(i);
            layoutChild(field, field.getPreferredWidth(), field
                    .getPreferredHeight());
            setPositionChild(field, (Constants.width - field
                    .getPreferredWidth()) >> 1, y);
            y += field.getPreferredHeight();
        }
        setExtent(maxWidth, HEIGHT);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your TableManager to a master manager that is not vertically Scrollable.

You may also use a simple VerticalFieldManager with any Field inside set to FIELD_HCENTER instead of using this TableManager.